# How to pass parameter from controller to another view (a form) inside a view

Tags: yii2

This is my actionIndex() in my controller.

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
     $featured= new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query'=>News::find()
        ->where(['not', ['featuredOrder' => null]])
        ->orderBy('featuredOrder'),
        ]);

     $checkList=Featured::find()
        ->joinWith('news')
        ->where(['news.featuredOrder'=>null])
        ->orderBy('featuredOrder')
        ->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $featured,
            'checkList'=>$checkList,
        ]);
```

I have a listview in my `index` view which is rendered by this controller. If an item of the listview is clicked, it will display the detailView of each item, along with the `update` button to update the item's data which will generate a form to update. I need to pass the $checklist to this form. Later I'll use this $checklist to populate a drop-down list. I wonder how to pass the parameter. I could just move this part to the form view, but I think it's not a good practice to have this inside a view.

```
     $checkList=Featured::find()
        ->joinWith('news')
        ->where(['news.featuredOrder'=>null])
        ->orderBy('featuredOrder')
        ->all();
```

This is my index :

```
<?php echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $featured,
       'itemView'=>'_post',
       'options'=>['class'=>'row'], 
       'itemOptions'=>['class'=>'col-md-4'], 
       'summary'=>'', 
       'viewParams'=>['cekList'=>'cekList'],
        'pager' => [
        'options'=>['class'=>'pagination justify-content-center'],
        'linkContainerOptions'=>['class'=>'page-item'],
        'linkOptions'=>['class'=>'page-link'],
```

_post view

```
div class = "panel panel-default">

            <div class = "panel-body">
                <h2 class="truncate text-center"><?=Html::a($model->title, ['view', 'id' => $model->id] ) ?>    </h2>
                <hr>
             </div>
 <!-- another block of code, but unrelated, so I won't include it -->
```

This is the view.php file,being rendered if an item's title in the `_post` above is clicked.

```
 <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
                'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                'data' => [
                    'confirm' => 'Do you want to delete this post?',
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]) ?>
```

If an update button is clicked, it will render a form. I want to pass the param to this form.

Comment: add related `view` files also.

Comment: Just updated. Please check it. Thanks @InsaneSkull

Comment: what kind of `params` in update?

Comment: This one : `$checkList=Featured::find()
        ->joinWith('news')
        ->where(['news.featuredOrder'=>null])
        ->orderBy('featuredOrder')
        ->all();`

Comment: So I want to make a drop down list in the form base on this active record result.

Comment: There is no need to pass `$checkList`in Params. You can add this query in update action then easily pass to rendered file.

Comment: Can I use this in my `index` view ? `$this->params['checklist'] = $checklist;` then in my form view to generate the dropdown I use this : `foreach($this->params['checklist'] as $model) {//do something};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207334/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-codejunkie).

Comment: isn't update action will only be called after an updated form is being submitted? I need it before the form is being submitted to generate a drop down list

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is Based On this Query :

```
$checkList=Featured::find()
        ->joinWith('news')
        ->where(['news.featuredOrder'=>null])
        ->orderBy('featuredOrder')
        ->all();
```

If you want to use only above query for drop down there is a two way to do that :

**1.**  Create A method in controller   and use **array helper** method for drop down list  add select statement in query

```
 public function checklistDropdown(){
       $items = Featured::find()
            ->joinWith('news')
            ->where(['news.featuredOrder'=>null])
            ->orderBy('featuredOrder')
            ->all();
      $items = ArrayHelper::map($items, 'id', 'name');
   }
```

In your **index** action  call this method pass just like you passed model and dataprovider

**2.** second option is more feasible i think

Create a component helper for generic drop down list add above method in that component and use that component to call the method in you view , you can define that method as **STATIC** . It will be reusable.